# My update tag function here isn't working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

Hi all I am new to angular and would like to know what I am doing wrong in this function.

I am trying to retrieve a firebase child array of tags and compare it with users tags and get an union and post that union back to the firebase array .

Here is my  function:

```
//this retrieved the tag arrays from firebase
$scope.utags = Tag.gettag();
```

This function converts a firebase array to a JS array .. I initialize it with `{{universaltags(utags)}}` from the view. Any attempt to initiate the function in the controller using `$scope.unversaltags($scope.utags);` gives me a blank array 
but it works with the views initiation.

```
$scope.universaltags = function(utag){
    var arr1 = [];  
    for (var i = 0 ; i < utag.length; i++) {
        arr1.push(utag[i].$value);
    }
    return arr1;
};
```

Also this is the function which I use to find the union and post it back to firebase.

```
$scope.universaltagupdate =   function union_arrays (x,y,Tag) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = x.length-1; i >= 0; -- i) {
        obj[x[i]] = x[i];
    }
    for (var i = y.length-1; i >= 0; -- i) {
        obj[y[i]] = y[i];
    }
    var res = [];
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {  // <-- optional
            res.push(obj[k]);
        }
    }
    //this uses a service to set firebase value 
    return Tag.updatetag(res);
}
```

I am not able to initialize both the functions within the controller.
Can you please tell me what is wrong with this approach and what can be the best way to achieve the result? Right now using the functions in curly braces show the results, but how do I accomplish this in the controller?

Comment: call to get firebase data is asynchronous...you can't work with the results until they are received. You don't appear to have any callbacks related to asynchronous actions

Comment: thanks charlietfl ..can you please show me how to make the async call ..  your help will be much appreciated.